# Convolution Layer CS321n

Tags: matrices, convolution, machine-learning

I am watching the cs231n stanford convolution series and have a question about the convolution part.

The image below shows a slide for the convolution part. The filter in this case is 3 dimensional.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiHUx.jpg)

Question 1: 
Why is it 3 dimensional? Shouldn't a filter just be 1 dimensional and then we do the dot product using that filter on the 3 layers of the input image?

eg
**Output of that single neuron = filter dot with Red Channel + filter dot with Blue Channel + filter dot with Green Channel.**

Question 2:
If the filter is 3 dimensional, is the math to do the convolution as follow:

**Output of that single neuron = 1st dimension filter dot with Red Channel + 2nd dimension filter dot with Blue Channel + 3rd dimension filter dot with Green Channel.**

Am i doing the convolution math correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let the input image be denoted $X$ of dimension $w \times h \times d$, and we have $n$ filters, denoted $F_i$, each of dimension $f \times f \times d$. The filter is always taken to have the same depth as the input image.

Applying this filter results in an output response map, $S$, which is a stack $S = \{ S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n\}$ where

$$
S_i = X * F_i ~~~ (+b_i)
$$

where $*$ is the convolution operator, and $b_i$ is an optional bias vector. So, the dimension of each $S_i$ is $(w-f+1) \times (h-f+1)$.

The filter is three dimensional so that the resulting image is of depth $1$. You could potentially use a filter of depth $1$ but then you have to convolve each of the $3$ layers of $X$ separately, I'm not sure how this would work out.

To figure out how to do the convolution, Let's focus on the easy case in which $d=1$, and let's take $f=3$ and $w = h = 6$. In this case, the dimension of $S$ is $4 \times 4 \times 1$.

Then our convolution would look something like:

$$
S =
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13} & \dots & X_{16} \\
X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23} & \dots & X_{26} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
X_{61} & X_{62} & X_{63} & \dots & X_{66} \\
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{11} & F_{12} & F_{13} \\
F_{21} & F_{22} & F_{23} \\
F_{31} & F_{32} & F_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So we have to pass the $F$ matrix over $3 \times 3$ sub matrices in S, the first such pass over would give us the *elementwise* multiplication:

$$
S_{11}=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13} \\
X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23} \\
X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{11} & F_{12} & F_{13} \\
F_{21} & F_{22} & F_{23} \\
F_{31} & F_{32} & F_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= X_{11}F_{11} + X_{12}F_{12} + \dots X_{33} F_{33}
$$

Now, we can write this as the *matrix multiplication* :

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
S_{11} \\
S_{12}\\
S_{13}\\
S_{14}\\
S_{21}\\
\vdots\\
S_{44}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13} & X_{21}& X_{22}& X_{23} & X_{31}& X_{32}& X_{33}\\
X_{12} & X_{13} & X_{14} &X_{22} & X_{23} & X_{24} & X_{32} & X_{33} & X_{34}  \\
X_{13} &&&&\dots \\
X_{14}  &&&&\dots \\
X_{21}  &&&&\dots \\
\vdots  &&&&\dots\\
X_{44}  &&&&\dots
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{11} \\
F_{12}\\
F_{13}\\
F_{21}\\
F_{22}\\
F_{23}\\
F_{31}\\
F_{32}\\
F_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

or more succinctly:

$$
\text{vec}(S) = M_X \text{vec}(F)
$$

where $M_X$ is the $16 \times 9$ matrix. Note that the first row of $M_X$ corresponds to the first $f \times f$ sub matrix of $X$ flattened out. The second row is the second submatrix, achieved by sliding the filter one step to the right, flattened out, and so on.. In general, when $d=1$, the dimension of $M_X$ is $(w-f+1)(h-f+1) \times f^2$.

Next, in the $d$ dimensional case, say $d=3$ for example, each pass over of the filter has three times as many multiplications as the 1 dimensional case. So each row of $M_X$ is now of length $d f^2$, i.e. $M_X$ is of dimension: $(w-f+1)(h-f+1) \times df^2$

Note that I have left out the bias vector in this discussion to avoid clogging up the presentation, but incorporating it should be straight forward.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Just a remark: You might consider using bmatrix instead of pmatrix because it allows a sharper rendering of matrix brackets.

Comment: @MrYouMath thanks for the suggestion, bmatrix does look a lot better!